# Best way to get follow links scrapy web crawler

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

So I'm trying to write a spider to continue clicking a `next` button on a webpage until it can't anymore (or until I add some logic to make it stop).  The code below correctly gets the link to the next page but prints it only once.  My question is why isn't it "following" the links that each next button leads to?

```
class MyprojectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'redditbot'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/nfl/?count=25&after=t3_7ax8lb']
    start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/nfl/?count=25&after=t3_7ax8lb']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        next_page = hxs.select('//div[@class="nav-buttons"]//a/@href').extract()
        if next_page:
            yield Request(next_page[1], self.parse)
            print(next_page[1])
```

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/nfl/?count=25&after=t3_7ax8lb page does not have any  data in it

Comment: Also `//div[@class="nav-buttons"]//a/@href` does not have any data

Answer (score 1):

To go to the next page, instead of printing the link you just need to yield a `scrapy.Request object` like the following code:

```
import scrapy

class MyprojectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myproject'
    allowed_domains = ['reddit.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/nfl/']

    def parse(self, response):
        posts = response.xpath('//div[@class="top-matter"]')
        for post in posts:
            # Get your data here
            title = post.xpath('p[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract()
            print(title)
            # Go to next page
            next_page = response.xpath('//span[@class="next-button"]/a/@href').extract_first()
            if next_page:
                 yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

**Update:** Previous code was wrong, needed to use the absolute URL and also some Xpaths were wrong, this new one should work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I saw this on the scrapy docs website too... but when I run it, only the link to the next page gets printed out and that's it.  Do I need to put it in a loop? How does it know to continue iterating?

Comment: Updated it now, the XPATHs were wrong and also needed to use the absolute URL, the initial URL you had: https://www.reddit.com/r/nfl/?count=25&after=t3_7ax8lb is not returning anything, seems like Reddit rotates this afters or something.

Comment: Just run `scrapy runspider yourspider.py ` with the code I posted to see the results.